# Compare two CString which contain Version no

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, compare, cstring

In a code I have 2 `CString` which contain a part of version number,
First exe contain version 1.1234.3.1 and the second exe has version 1.2.3.1.

Code should be such that

Suppose

```
CString MinVreg,MinFref;

if(MinVreg<MinFref) //when MinVreg="1234" and MinFref="2"

{
    //it enters in if loop.
    //Update registry
}
elseif(MinVreg>MinFref)
{
   //Show message box..
}
```

I think the operator check only first digit.So please tell me how to compare it as a number

Comment: You should wait for the "Perfect Answer". The solution provided by @Sivaraman is a poor piece of code with unnecessary and pointless castings although it provides the answer in context of your question (tell me how to compare it as a number) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the strings to represent a version as an integer array, then perform a lexicographic compare.

```
bool ParseVersionString(unsigned digits[4], const CString& i_version)
  {
  return sscanf(i_version, "%d.%d.%d.%d", &digits[0], &digits[1], 
                &digits[2], &digits[3]) == 4;
  }

int CompareVersions(unsigned ver1[4], unsigned ver2[4])
  {
  for (int i = 0; i != 4; ++i)
    {
    if (ver1[i] < ver2[i])
      return -1;
    if (ver1[i] > ver2[i])
      return 1;
    }

  return 0;
  }
```

Usage:

```
  CString MinVreg("1.1234.3.1"), MinFref("1.2.3.1");
  unsigned ver1[4], ver2[4];
  if (ParseVersionString(ver1, MinVreg) &&
      ParseVersionString(ver2, MinFref) &&
      CompareVersions(ver1, ver2) < 0)
  {
  //Update registry
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    if ( atoi((char*)(LPCTSTR)MinVreg) <  atoi((char*)(LPCTSTR)MinFref)
    {
    //Do the Stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [strstr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9da80kz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) function to check if the `character` is present or not.

```
if( NULL != strstr(MinVreg, MinFref) )
{
    //enter the loop
}
```

**EDIT**::
If you want to compare them as `int`, you need to convert them to `int`.

```
if( atoi(MinVreg) < atoi(MinFref) )
{
    //MinVreg < MinFref, Do something
}
elseif( atoi(MinVreg) > atoi(MinFref) )
{
    //MinVreg > MinFref, Do something
}
else
{
     //MinVreg = MinFref, Do something
}
```

**UPDATE**:: After question data edited to `MinVreg = 1.1234.3.1 and MinFref = 1.2.3.1`

```
int a ;
a = strcmp( MinVreg, MinFref ) ;
if( a < 0 )
{
    //MinVreg < MinFref, Do something
}
elseif( a > 0 )
{
    //MinVreg > MinFref, Do something
}
else
{
     //MinVreg = MinFref, Do something
}
```

Comment: @vikky- I can't understand, how the above solution is accepted. This is much better solution than the other one.

Comment: @Abhineet if MinVreg=234 and MinFref=2 then it enter in the loop.

Comment: Yeah now it made sense to me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why use strings in the first place? Here's how I keep track of versions.

```
BOOL GetProductVersion(VS_FIXEDFILEINFO &fixedFileInfo, LPCTSTR szFileName)
{
    DWORD dwHandle = 0;
    DWORD dwLen = GetFileVersionInfoSize(szFileName, &dwHandle);
    if (dwLen == 0)
        return FALSE;

    LPSTR lpVI = new CHAR[dwLen];
    if (!lpVI)
        return FALSE;

    ZeroMemory(lpVI, dwLen);

    GetFileVersionInfo(szFileName, dwHandle, dwLen, lpVI);

    DWORD dwBufSize;
    VS_FIXEDFILEINFO* lpFFI;
    if (VerQueryValue(lpVI, "\\", (LPVOID*)&lpFFI, (PUINT)&dwBufSize))
    {
        fixedFileInfo = *lpFFI;
        delete [] lpVI;

        return TRUE;
    }

    delete [] lpVI;

    return FALSE;
}

CString GetProductVersionAsString(LPCTSTR szFileName)
{
    CString version;

    VS_FIXEDFILEINFO ffi;
    if (GetProductVersion(ffi, szFileName))
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << HIWORD(ffi.dwProductVersionMS) << '.';
        ss << LOWORD(ffi.dwProductVersionMS) << '.';
        ss << HIWORD(ffi.dwProductVersionLS);

        UINT beta = LOWORD(ffi.dwProductVersionLS);
        if (beta)
            ss << " beta" << beta;

        version = ss.str().c_str();
    }

    return version;
}

DWORD GetProductVersionAsInteger(LPCTSTR szFileName)
{
    DWORD version = 0;

    VS_FIXEDFILEINFO ffi;
    if (GetProductVersion(ffi, szFileName))
    {
        // Apply your number logic here!
        // This code is suitable for x.y.z
        version += 100 * HIWORD(ffi.dwProductVersionMS);
        version += 10 * LOWORD(ffi.dwProductVersionMS);
        version += HIWORD(ffi.dwProductVersionLS);
    }

    return version;
}
```

Hence, "1.0.2" becomes 102. Obviously, larger version numbers need other multipliers.

Comment: We have to fetch the version of exe from the registry and the version of the exe from folder,Then we have to compare it.

Comment: Then parse it and use the same logic. I would tokenize the string using the dots and then OR each part into an integer - 8 bits for each part. Though, I believe Andrey's answer is sufficient!